# How get the part of the image?

Tags: php, image

Let's say I have many images. All those images have a black border of 5px. I want to delete all those borders via PHP. How can I do that? Is it possible to copy and move image like $newImage = oldImage(+5px height, +5 left etc.) or somehow similar?

Comment: Did you read [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.image.php) on `gd`?

Comment: Lots of questions here on cropping images. Since you have a fixed border size, it should be easy to adapt many of them to suit your needs, cropping the outer 5px off all dimensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$size=getimagesize($oldfilename);
$image=imagecreatefromgd2part ($oldfilename , 5, 5, $size[0]-10, $size[1]-10);
imagejpeg($image,$newfilename);
```

Answer (score 0):

I thinks that could work:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresampled.php